# SwiftUI + MapBox integration messes up navbar

Tags: swiftui, mapbox

I'm implementing some MapBox functionality in SwiftUi and when using the default NavigationBar everything works as expected:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MapView(annotations: $annotations)
                .centerCoordinate(.init(latitude: 37.791293, longitude: -122.396324))
                .navigationBarTitle("Hello")
        }
}
```

shows:

[image: Image 1]

But when trying to have an .inline style for the navBar, the view behaves weird:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MapView(annotations: $annotations)
                .centerCoordinate(.init(latitude: 37.791293, longitude: -122.396324))
                .navigationBarTitle("Hello", displayMode: .inline)
                //.navigationBarColor(.parqGreen)
        }
}
```

[image: Image 2]

And when adding color:

[image: Image 3]

Any idea why this happens ? Is it something in the MapBox framework ?

Update: Added MapView:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var annotations: [MGLPointAnnotation]

    private let mapView: MGLMapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: MGLStyle.streetsStyleURL)

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MGLMapView {
        mapView.logoView.isHidden = true
        mapView.attributionButton.isHidden = true
        mapView.zoomLevel = 13

        if let styleURL = URL(string: "mapbox://styles/morreke/cjkz2y4bq0kb12smmigszo70w") {
            mapView.styleURL = styleURL
        }
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
        updateAnnotations()
    }

    private func updateAnnotations() {
        if let currentAnnotations = mapView.annotations {
            mapView.removeAnnotations(currentAnnotations)
        }
        mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
    }

    func centerCoordinate(_ centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> MapView {
        mapView.centerCoordinate = centerCoordinate
        return self
    }
}
```

Update 2: Even the simplest implementation has the same result

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    private let mapView: MGLMapView = MGLMapView()

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MGLMapView {

        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work as expected in my test (though without the `centerCoordinate` modifier). Can you show your `MapView` code?

Comment: I have edited my post with the MapView.swift (Just removed the coordinator for code simplicity)

Comment: I still can't reproduce the behaviour you're seeing. I couldn't access your `styleURL` so just swapped in `MGLStyle.outdoorsStyleURL` but that's unlikely to be the problem. If you swap `mapView.attributionButton.isHidden = true` to `false` does that have an effect? It is Mapbox's telemetry opt-out that they insist appears 'somewhere'.

Comment: Even the simplest implementation of MGLMapView shows the same behavior

Comment: I'll update Xcode from Version 11.3.1 to 11.4.1 and see what that gives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Xcode from 11.3.1 to 11.4.1 did the trick.

Comment: This was driving me mad. Glad the fix was so straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it :)